# event handler not working with dynamically generated xaml button

Tags: c#, xaml

```
private void createCarers()
    {
        foreach (Carer c in CarerManager.Carers.Values)
        {
            Button x = new Button
            {
                Content = c.name,
                MinHeight = 50,
                Tag = c,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10)
            };
            x.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(carerClick);
            carersPanel.Children.Add(x);
        }
    }

    private void carerClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

Ok so `createCarers` is called when the window is initialised.

Why does this not work? The shutdown thing is just a test but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by `Why does this not work`? You mean when you click on the button nothing happens?

Comment: yes thats what I mean

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in `carerClick` method and try debugging the code to see if the method is actually executing when you click the button?

Comment: seems like its not

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Don't do that. Use [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), define ItemTemplate for your Carer class with command bound to the button and bind your CarerManager.Carers.Values to ItemsControl.ItemsSource. For now it seems like an overkill, but this is how it should be done

Comment: I like my approach but it should work.